# How to Combine Insert, Update, and Delete in the same `Instead Of` Trigger, in Oracle db?

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql, dml

When creating an `Instead Of` trigger, Sql Developer allows to include all 3 DML actions in the same trigger:

[image]

The result SQL looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
INSTEAD OF DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON PO_COSTED_BOM_V 
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

I'm able to combine `Insert` and `Update` like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON PO_COSTED_BOM_V 
BEGIN
  UPDATE SRC_TBL SET CFG_VALUE = :NEW.CFG_VALUE
  WHERE CFG_NAME = :NEW.CFG_NAME;
  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO SRC_TBL (CFG_NAME, CFG_VALUE) 
         VALUES(:NEW.CFG_NAME, :NEW.CFG_VALUE);
  END IF;
END;
```

- But how do i get the `Delete` statement into the trigger?
- How does the trigger know which DML action was executed?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Coding the Trigger Body](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#i1025109)

> Detecting the DML Operation that Fired a Trigger
>
> If more than one type of DML operation can fire a trigger (for
>   example, ON INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF emp), the trigger body can
>   use the conditional predicates INSERTING, DELETING, and UPDATING to
>   check which type of statement fire the trigger.
>
> Within the code of the trigger body, you can execute blocks of code
>   depending on the kind of DML operation that fired the trigger:
>
> ```
> IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;
> IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;
> IF DELETING THEN ... END IF;
> ```

in your case

```
...
if inserting then

INSERT INTO SRC_TBL (CFG_NAME, CFG_VALUE) 
         VALUES(:NEW.CFG_NAME, :NEW.CFG_VALUE);

elsif updating then

 UPDATE SRC_TBL SET CFG_VALUE = :NEW.CFG_VALUE
  WHERE CFG_NAME = :NEW.CFG_NAME;

elsif deleting then

 ...

END IF;
```

Comment: great! thx much

Comment: extra credit: currently, manual update in the grid of the view in Sql Dev is treated as a direct edit of the view (which therefore fails, since my view is not updatable)-- it does *not* fire the trigger. Is it possible to make a grid edit fire the trigger? Or does Sql Dev offer an alternate native grid which could fire the trigger? if possible, i shall post as a new question so others can benefit.

Comment: the best, you post a new question, with the definition of the view and the trigger.

Comment: is the `else` required? Can't we just do `IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;
IF DELETING THEN ... END IF;`

Comment: no, the elsif  is not requied, many ways lead to Rome :)